# Adding NSStrings Together Rounding Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsstring

I have a simple app that I am trying to make add two NSStrings together and produce the value in a label.

```
NSString *one= @"0.00";
NSString *two= @"20.15";

NSString *total = [[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat:@"%d",[one integerValue] + [two integerValue]];

label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",total];
```

This works fine except I want it to take in account the numbers past the decimal. The output becomes 20 and not 20.15.

Comment: Amazing, three answers, not one used the easy `NSString stringWithFormat:` from the question!

Comment: @Zaph haha, we copied and pasted OP's code.

Comment: Hey guys just want to say thanks again for the quick answers though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use floats instead of integers

```
NSString *total = [[NSString alloc]  initWithFormat:@"%f",[one floatValue] + [two floatValue]];
```

If you want to specify 2 decimal places, replace `%f` with `%.2f`

Note, `[two integerValue]` evaluates to `20` in your example. You lose the decimal precision from that point on.

Answer (score 2):

Find the `floatValue` of the `NSString` instead of the `intValue`. Integers are whole numbers, so anything after the decimal point is ignored.

```
NSString *one= @"0.00";
NSString *two= @"20.15";

NSString *total = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [one floatValue] + [two floatValue]];

label.text = total;
```

Comment: Thank you. So many quick answers +1. But since you were the first that was accurate you are the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Integers don't have decimals.

Try:

```
NSString *total = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [one floatValue] + [two floatValue]];
```